# jQuery toggle(), how to select a dom element that changes another dom element

Tags: jquery

When a person clicks on the question that is within the H4 tags, I want to toggle the answers that are located in the P tags that are underneath in the html code. Totally new to jQuery. Wasn't sure how to word this question to locate an answer in the search. Thanks for the help community!

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#part3 h4").click(function()
        {
            $("p").toggle();
        }
    });
</script>
<div id="part3">
    <h2>3: FAQ Hide/Show Demo</h2>
    <a href="#">Show All</a> | <a href="#">Hide All</a>
    <div class="faq">          
            <h4>1.How much does it cost? </h4>
            <div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                 sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna 
                  <strong>aliquam</strong> erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
                 exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea 
                 commodo consequat. </p>
            </div>
            <h4>2.What is the meaning of life? </h4>
            <div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                 sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt<strong> ut laoreet dolore</strong> magna 
                 a<em>liquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi e</em>nim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
                 exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea 
                 commodo consequat. </p>
            </div>
            <h4>3.Why is the sky blue?</h4>
            <div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                 sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet <strong>dolore magna 
                 aliquam</strong> erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
                 exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea 
                 commodo consequat. </p>
            </div>
            <h4>4.Why is the real cost of money?</h4>
            <div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                 sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna 
                 aliquam erat volutpat. <strong>Ut wisi enim ad minim</strong> veniam, quis nostrud 
                 exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea 
                 commodo consequat. </p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read the section of the jQuery documentation on DOM traversal functions. It's extremely straightforward.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: also I think you should toggle the `div` element not the `p` element

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a8UTU/2/

Comment: awesome, thanks so much. it totally works

Comment: @khmer2040 I'll post it as an answer then

Answer (score 1):

You can use this inside the click handler.

```
$(this).next().find('p').toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an accordion layout you are trying to build, also it will be better if you toggle the `div` element instead of the `p` elements.

Also to enable the show/hide all functionality

```
<a href="#" class="showall">Show All</a> | <a href="#" class="hideall">Hide All</a>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#part3 h4").click(function () {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
    $("#part3 .showall").click(function () {
        $("#part3 .faq > div").show();
    });
    $("#part3 .hideall").click(function () {
        $("#part3 .faq > div").hide();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a8UTU/)

In the click function you need to target the next sibling element of the clicked `h4` element, so you need to use the [tree traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) function [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next)

Comment: also, with the same code, how would I use jQuery to change the css of the contents of the h4 tag. I have a css created as
.faq h4.over {color:#990000; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline}

Comment: there is no need to us jQuery just use the [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo class like `.faq h4:hover {
    color:#990000;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:underline
}`